# What should be stored in a maven repository?

Tags: maven, repository, artifactory, artifacts

Should I store artifacts that are final products, not to be used as a dependency of another project within a maven repository? i.e. EAR, WAR, zip, tar, etc.

I've been unable to find any documents that explicitly state whether this is the proper usage or not but I see that there are EAR/WAR/zip/tar files in Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cp%3A%22war%22

Is anyone aware of any documentation to support either position?

Comment: Why would you want to do that.. ?

Comment: So I can store final versions of artifacts for deployment. Are there specific reasons why I wouldn't want to do that?

Comment: I can't think of anything stopping you from doing it, although it does mean you're mixing deployable packages with dependency jars which isn't ideal. I'd prefer to keep deployable artifacts stored in a separate build tool like jenkins for easy deployment.

Comment: Usually you have an internal repository manager which contains your releases and there you store also EAR/WAR/ZIP/TAR and from that repo manager you can download all to deploy things on the appropriate servers. Jenkins is not intended to store artifacts...

Comment: thanks @khmarbaise. Would you say that having a unique maven repo for deployable artifacts that is separate from the shareable maven repo would be the proper way to structure this or are you suggesting a completely different type of repo (ie a deployment tool that has a built in repo)?

Comment: The best practice here is to have a separate repo for 'deployable' (i.e. production-ready) artifacts which you promote there after they have passed certain quality 'gates' (your tests, qa etc.) while keeping dependencies in a separate repo (i.e. remote proxy to [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) which you can use as shared resources for all of your builds.  There's no 'rule' against keeping everything together - just a logical separation to help you manage artifacts better.